# Octave solve multiple ODE systems

Tags: octave

I know I can use Octave built-in ODE solver to solve a ODE system. Now I want to solve the multiple ODE systems of the same structure but with different coefficients. For example, I have the following ODEs:

function xdot=f(x,t)

```
a = 0.1;

xdot(1) = a * x(1) ^ 2 + x(2);
xdot(2) = x(1) - x(2);
```

endfunction

Initial conditions x(1)=0, x(2)=0 at t=0. I want to get x(1) and x(2) at point t=1. I know I can solve this easily by using lsode command.

Now I want to change the value "a" from 0.1 to 20 with step 0.1, that is a=[0.1:0.1:20]. So I can get x(1) and x(2) from different "a". How do I do this in a loop? Do I need a global variable "a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I've ever used `lsode` before, but when I've had a variable in a function that I've wanted to change, I've had to declare it a global variable and then redefine the function. Something like

```
%doesn't work
f = @(x) a*x+2
for a= 0.1:0.1:20
  f(1)
end

%does work  
for a= 0.1:0.1:20
  f = @(x) a*x+2 %your function here
  %I usually end up using arrayfun() here in my applications, maybe lsode would work?
end
```

I'm no Octave expert, but this has worked for me, so maybe it'll work for you too.

Comment: I guess the global variable is working. I figured out that I can also pass in the variable that I want to change as a parameter to the function.